# Как сделать относительный путь к библиотеке?

Tags: c++, qt5, dll, mingw, qmake

Как сделать относительный путь к dll?

Структура файлов:

```
- root
    - myProg
        * myProg.exe
    - myLib
        * myLib.dll
    - someLib
        * someLib.dll
```

**UDP:** пока не понял как сделать файл манифеста, где нужно относительный путь указывать к библиотеке?

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

Answer (score 0):

Желательно не хардкодить пути к библиотекам в коде. Вам правильно подсказали [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) (дополню еще для [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime) и для [OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274/is-it-ok-to-use-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-whats-the-dynamic-library-s)). Размещайте библиотеки там, где система может их найти. Если вы хотите их упрятать в отдельные директории, то указывайте относительные пути (имя_директории/mylib.so).

Comment: Оччень интересно, за что минусов напихали... о0